# Change the color of the options a drop down menu using JavaScript or jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a ,<select> (drop down) in which I want to change the colors of its options. But I want to change the color of the option text partially, that is, only the specified text of option would be of the specified color.

Like, if the option is **22 kg**, then I want to give color only to 'kg'.

Comment: Are you trying to make a drop down navigation, or style `<select>` in a form?

Comment: why does this have to be done using jquery/javascript, can you not just use css?

Comment: @martincarlin87 - sure, css could also do.

Comment: @bookcasey : it is a <select>

Comment: Styling dropdown menus isn't something I can recall doing, perhaps it is more difficult that I first imagined but I found this question which might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Much to my surprise, making content of an `<option>` tag partially a different color (for example with a `span` as motoxer4533 suggested) didn't work. Some searching on SO lead me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat) suggesting it's not valid to do fancy things with options.

Leftover options would be to create your "own" select-like behavior. You mentioned `jQuery` as a tag in your question, perhaps [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has something you need (though I don't believe they have a custom dropdown control)?

Edit: this possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223074/bold-part-of-an-option-in-a-drop-down-list)? Questions are slightly different, but answers are the same.

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the kg in a `span` tag, like:

```
<option>22<span>kg</span></option>
```

and then style the span like:

```
option span {
    color:red
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)'s answers suggest that's not valid / won't work. (much to my own surprise :S)