# How can I partially style text within a dropdown?

Tags: css

I have these dropdowns, and really need some way to format some of the text within them.

I would like to achieve something like:

```
<option value="8470621">Corey Perry <i>Anaheim Mighty Ducks</i></option>
<option value="8474141"><b>Patrick Kane</b> Chicago Blackhawks</option>
```

But browsers do not seem to support this.

Italics or bolding would really be best, but if there was any type of text formatting (subscript, font color) it would probably be better than just bracketing them.

Comment: [The only content that may be inside an option tag is text](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-option-element).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bold part of an option in a drop down list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223074/bold-part-of-an-option-in-a-drop-down-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your options for styling `option` tags in a dropdown is fairly limited. There are alternatives to native `select` boxes though. Check out this robust jQuery plugin called [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Answer (score 1):

You can style drop downs somewhat via CSS (and it will vary from browser to browser). If you MUST have advanced styling, you'll want to create your own 'layer' via JS and CSS on top that you can customize all you want that then, behind the scenes, updates the hidden drop down.