# bold text in <select> list

Tags: html, select

Dear people I am doing a list of card games and in some cases I would want the second name to be in bold.

http://gjallur.net/galdur/Cards1.htm

Is there a way to do that?
I tried it with `<b></b>` tags but that does not work.

```
<select>
<option value="90"> Manni </option>
<option value="91"> Manni - Haraldarmanni </option>
<option value="93"> Manni - Hornafjarðarmanni </option>
<option value="94"> Manni - Laugarvatnsmanni </option>
<option value="92"> Manni - Trjámann </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can do it using `nth-child` selector: `option:nth-child(2) { font-weight:bold; }` Won't work in Chrome though.

Comment: No. You either have the whole `option` bold or not. In order to have rich text inside a `select` you'll need a plugin or something to convert them into markup and JS.

Comment: @APAD1 no he can't `nth-child` will select the entire `<option>`. He wants the second name of each `<option>` to be bold (for example: `<option value="91"> Manni - <b>Haraldarmanni</b> </option>` note: pseudo-code).

Comment: Updated my comment, it works fine in FireFox, not so much in Chrome.

Comment: @BenM, I see now. Disregard my initial comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bold part of an option in a drop down list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223074/bold-part-of-an-option-in-a-drop-down-list)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is impossible! Because select element is rendered by the OS and not HTML. **It cannot be styled via CSS.** So you have to think alternative .I thought to create a dropdown  from `<ul> list` and `<li>` options.So I created this one bellow: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ks09u3kd/
.And now **YES** you have can whatever option you want in whatever style!

**DROPDOWN WITH UL AND LI AS HTML SELECT ELEMENT**

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  var open = [];

  var opts = {
    selector: '.dropdown',
    toggle: 'dropdown-toggle',
    open: 'dropdown-open',
    nest: true
  };

  $(document).on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown', function(e) {
    // Close the last open dropdown if click is from outside the target dropdown
    if (open.length && (!opts.nest || !open[open.length - 1].find(e.target).length)) {
      open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
    }

    var $this = $(e.target);

    // If target is a dropdown then toggle it...
    if ($this.hasClass(opts.toggle)) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $this = $this.closest(opts.selector);

      if (!$this.hasClass(opts.open)) {
        open.push($this.addClass(opts.open));
      } else {
        open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
      }
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* toggle */

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  padding: 0;
}
/* dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
}
/* options */

.dropdown-menu .option a {
  padding: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu .option a:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
/* open */

.dropdown-open {
  z-index: 400;
}
.dropdown-open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSelect" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#options" class="dropdown-toggle">Manni </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="option"><a href="#">Manni - Haraldarmanni</a>
    </li>
    <li class="option"><a href="#">Manni - Hornafjarðarmanni</a>
    </li>
    <li class="option"><a href="#">Manni - Laugarvatnsmanni</a>
    </li>
    <li class="option"><a href="#">Manni - Trjámann</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we were to code what you ask in pure JS: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ld82d23/)

```
<div id="fakeSelect">
    <div id="selectBox"></div>
    <ul id="selectOptionsBox">
        <li>Manni</li>
        <li>Manni - Haraldarmanni</li>
        <li>Manni - <b>Hornafjarðarmanni</b></li>
        <li>Manni - Laugarvatnsmanni</li>
        <li>Marglita hálfmáninn</li>
        <li>Marglita klukkan</li>
        <li>Marías</li>
        <li>Mausel</li>
        <li>Málverkasafnið</li>
        <li>Mexíkanskur veltipóker</li>
        <li>Miklar hindranir</li>
        <li>Monte Carlo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
#fakeSelect {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#selectBox {
    width: calc(200px - 4px);
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: default;
    font: 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
#selectBox:hover {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
#selectBox::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "▼";
    font-size: .8em;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
#selectOptionsBox {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: default;
    font: 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    display: none;
}
#selectOptionsBox li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#selectOptionsBox li:hover {
    background: gainsboro;
}
```

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var selectOptionsBox = document.getElementById("selectOptionsBox");
var selectOptions = selectOptionsBox.getElementsByTagName("li");

selectBox.innerHTML = selectOptions[0].innerHTML;

selectBox.onclick = function() {
    if (selectOptionsBox.style.display != "block") {
        selectOptionsBox.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        selectOptionsBox.style.display = "none";
    }
}
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target != selectBox &&
        selectOptionsBox.style.display == "block") {
        selectOptionsBox.style.display = "none";
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        selectOptions[i].onclick = function() {
            selectBox.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        }
    })(i);
}
```